# Leakcanary shows fragment leak with AppCompatActivity and FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I've been having this issue for a while now and I really don't know what else to try. I've stuck Leakcanary on my project so I can force myself to learn android 'the right way' without picking up patterns that cause memory leaks.. I'm building an app and I've stripped it down a lot and I still see this leak happening.

I have an Activity which has a viewpager inside and instantiates 10 fragments. If I turn the device everything seems fine, it's not until I press on 'Home' that I get the following memory leak:

```
D/LeakCanary﹕ In com.doesnthaveadomain.leo.calendartracker:1.0:1.
D/LeakCanary﹕ * com.doesnthaveadomain.leo.calendartracker.MyFragment has leaked:
D/LeakCanary﹕ * GC ROOT static android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.sDefaultWindowManager
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.mRoots
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references java.util.ArrayList.array
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.view.ViewRootImpl.mInvalidateOnAnimationRunnable
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.view.ViewRootImpl$InvalidateOnAnimationRunnable.mViews
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references java.util.ArrayList.array
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.mAdapter
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.doesnthaveadomain.leo.calendartracker.MyAdapter.mCurrentPrimaryItem
D/LeakCanary﹕ * leaks com.doesnthaveadomain.leo.calendartracker.MyFragment instance
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(5);
    }

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int mNumberOfViews;
    private final WeakReference<AppCompatActivity> mActivityWeakRef;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
                     AppCompatActivity activity) {
        super(fm);

        mActivityWeakRef = new WeakReference<AppCompatActivity>(activity);
        mNumberOfViews = 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        AppCompatActivity activity = mActivityWeakRef.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            MyApp.getRefWatcher(mActivityWeakRef.get()).watch(myFragment);
        }
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumberOfViews;
    }
}
```

MainActivity Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Popup">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    }

}
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem as my other issue, I was initializing the ref watcher at the wrong time, on fragment creation instead of on destroy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32881096/5278339